# My Magento site on Macbook is not picking up .css and .js because paths are wrong, where can I set these paths?

Tags: javascript, migration, paths

I have pulled whole Magento web site from a git repository onto my Macbook. It looks like the css and js files don't have the right path, and site doesn't look good (site is now without any styles). Paths for my css look like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/libraccio/js/solrsearch/autocomplete.css
```

Where can I set these paths so they are picked up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your website url's are correct within the `core_config_data` table.

`web/unsecure/base_url`

`web/secure/base_url`

Should be http://127.0.0.1/

unless you want to set a hostfile record and use a domain instead.

Comment: Thanks, this, with combining this solution:  

1.SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%merge%';
2.Set the values to 0  

Solved the problem